# Spring JdbcTemplate throws error on creating store procedure

Tags: java, mysql, spring, stored-procedures

I have a funny problem in creating SP for MariaDB.
When I execute below DDL straight away from HeidiSQL (db client app for MySql), I can create the SP easily.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `sp_delete_merchant`;

CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_delete_merchant`(IN `mer_id` BIGINT)
BEGIN
  DECLARE stop BIT DEFAULT FALSE;
  DECLARE comm_id BIGINT;
  DECLARE commodities CURSOR FOR SELECT id FROM tbl_commodity WHERE merchant_id = mer_id;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET stop = TRUE;

  # DELETE RECORDS FROM tbl_package2commodity BASED ON COMMODITY ID
  OPEN commodities;
    read_loop: LOOP
      FETCH commodities INTO comm_id;
      DELETE FROM tbl_package2commodity WHERE commodity_id = comm_id;
      IF stop THEN
        LEAVE read_loop;
      END IF;
    END LOOP;
  CLOSE commodities;

  # DELETE RECORDS FROM OTHER TABLES BASED ON MERCHANT ID
  DELETE FROM tbl_commodity WHERE merchant_id = mer_id;
  DELETE FROM tbl_package WHERE merchant_id = mer_id;
  DELETE FROM tbl_contact_person WHERE merchant_id = mer_id;
  DELETE FROM tbl_sales_force WHERE merchant_id = mer_id;
  DELETE FROM tbl_merchant WHERE id = mer_id;
END;
```

But when I try to execute the above DDL from Spring **JdbcTemplate** as below code:

```
public class DbStoreProceduresCreator implements InitializingBean {

    private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DbStoreProceduresCreator.class);

    @Value("classpath:com/litaal/commerce/config/setup_store_procedures.sql")
    private Resource createStoreProcedures;

    @Autowired
    private DataSource coreDS;

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        BufferedReader br = null;
        StringBuffer sql = new StringBuffer();
        try {
            InputStream is = createStoreProcedures.getInputStream();
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sql.append(line);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (br != null) {
                br.close();
            }
        }
        if (sql.length() > 0) {
            try {
                JdbcTemplate tmp = new JdbcTemplate(coreDS);
                tmp.execute(sql.toString());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It throws error like below:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
```

And I already try to googling it and change my script like ten times or more, and still couldn't find what is wrong with my DDL.

The reason why I want to create the SP from my java app is to make my app as portable as possible without any need to do anything to DB.

Comment: Can you log the sql variable and make sure the value is getting populated properly?

Comment: I would guess that the problem is with the separators. - execute the first line (`DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `sp_delete_merchant`;`) in a single `tmp.execute` and then execute the secondpart in a second invocation. An other thing that concerns me a bit, are your string quotes.

Comment: technically you don't need a back tick in any of it. It is not as if the rest of your code is following the back tick pattern. Perhaps it is a driver issue with separators. What works in mysql cli is not always going to work once pumpled thru a certain driver. Take for instance cron. One would have to know the intricacies of escaping characters at times. Also, once this is setup at the db level or a migration script, none of this DDL is needed. Are your rank in file queries working ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last ... I found the answer.
The problem is lies on how **JdbcTemplate** executes SQL script. It executes line by line (separated by new line). So I changed part of my code to remove all new lines, like below

```
....

if (sql.length() > 0) {
    String query = sql.toString().replaceAll("\\n", " ");
    query = query.replaceAll("\\t", " ");
    log.info(query);
    try {
        JdbcTemplate tmp = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
        tmp.execute(query);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error(e.getMessage());
    }
}
...
```

Now everything works like charm.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the `JdbcTemplate` cannot execute SQL procedures with comments (`#`) (`--`) in them that occur during select/updates, etc. The `JdbcTemplate` does support the (`--`, `#`) comments at the beginning of a statement such that:

```
-- --------------------------------------------
-- Summary Comments!
-- Note: This comes before a delimited statement (;). 
# These are okay too.
-- --------------------------------------------
SELECT * 
FROM User
-- This comment fails.
WHERE id > 0;
```

Here's how I'm breaking down procedures (from MySQL).

**Procedure**

```
USE `DbName`;
DROP procedure IF EXISTS `ProcName`;

DELIMITER $$
USE `DbName`$$
CREATE PROCEDURE `ProcName` ()
BEGIN
    # Here's a comment that would normally fail.
    SELECT 
        u.id        
    FROM
    User as u       
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

**Parser**

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
String[] lines = script.split("\n");

String delimiter = ";";

for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    String line = lines[i];

    if (line.contains("DELIMITER")) {
        String[] tokens = line.split(" ");
        delimiter = tokens[1];
        builder = new StringBuilder();
        continue;
    }

    //Comments cannot be executed properly by the JdbcTemplate, strip them out. 
    if (line.contains("#")) {               
        line = line.substring(0, line.indexOf('#'));
    }

    if (line.contains(delimiter)) {
        builder.append(line.replace(delimiter, ""));
        template.execute(builder.toString());
        builder = new StringBuilder();
    } else {
        builder.append(line);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there are several problems with your code, but one is, that `JdbcTemplate.execute(String sql)` execute only a single statement

```
/**
 * Issue a single SQL execute, typically a DDL statement.
 * @param sql static SQL to execute
 * @throws DataAccessException if there is any problem
 */
void execute(String sql) throws DataAccessException;
```

So you must split your execution in two executions, one for `DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS "sp_delete_merchant";`  and one for the rest.

BTW: you should have a look at [`org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/init/ScriptUtils.html)

*An other thing that concerns me a bit, are your string quotes.*